# Understanding algebraic operations on vector bundles

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles

Let $X$ be a smooth manifold with vector bundles $V$ and $W$. I'm trying to understand how we can construct in general a vector bundle $V \otimes W$.

In particular what manifold structure do we give $V$ and $W$? As a set I understand that:  $$V \otimes W = \{ (x,a) : a \in V_x \otimes W_x \}$$

Thanks to Travis' comments my understanding is now as follows:

$V$ and $W$ each have local trivialisation $\Phi_V: \pi_V^{-1}(U) \to U \times \mathbb{R}^k$ and similarly for $W$. Using this we can construct local coordinates on the set $V \otimes W$ above by choosing local coordinates on $U \times \mathbb{R}^k \times \mathbb{R}^l$, however I am struggling to figure out the details of this.

I'm now also wondering how we use the local trivialisation of $V$ and $W$ to construct a local trivialisation for $V \otimes W$?

I would also appreciate it if anyone could recommend a reference for such things - the textbook I am using (Lee) doesn't mention algebraic operations on vector bundles.

Thank you

Comment: Try Milnor--Stasheff, _Characteristic Classes_. Theorem 3.6 gives a very general statement along the lines you want. The proof is only sketched, but I think it gives the main idea quite well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The confusion here seems to be one of linear algebra, and not of differential geometry. The elements of a tensor product $\Bbb V \otimes \Bbb W$ of two vector spaces can be written as sums $\sum_a v_a \otimes w_a$, and this is enough to describe the manifold structure on the tensor product vector bundle $V \times W \to X$.

Choosing bases $(E_1, \ldots, E_k)$ of $\Bbb V$ and $(F_1, \ldots, F_l)$ of $\Bbb W$ determines a basis $(E_a \otimes F_b)_{1 \leq a \leq k, 1 \leq b \leq l}$ of $\Bbb V \otimes \Bbb W$, which has $\dim(\Bbb V \otimes \Bbb W) = \dim \Bbb V \cdot \dim \Bbb W = kl$ elements. With this basis in hand, we can choose coordinates $(x_i, y_{ab})$ for the vector bundle $V \otimes W$ (which has rank $kl$) with model fiber $\Bbb V \otimes \Bbb W$ by treating the latter as any other vector space for which we've picked a basis.

By contrast, the above choice of bases determine a basis $(E_1, \ldots, E_k, F_1, \ldots, F_k)$ of the direct sum $\Bbb V \oplus \Bbb W$, which has dimension $\dim(\Bbb V \oplus \Bbb W) = \dim \Bbb V + \dim \Bbb W = k + l$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How do you know in general that a vector bundle has coordinates of that form though? My understanding was that a vector bundle is just some manifold with a projection map?

Comment: Actually I think I understand - so we create a new manifold structure on $V \times W$ just thinking of them as sets again and then introduce coordinates as you describe? Is it easy to show that that is again a vector bundle? Presumably that is where we need to use the fact that $V$ and $W$ are vector bundles to begin with?

Comment: Apologies for the triple comment! In particular I'm struggling to see how the local trivialisation for $V$ and $W$ give us a local trivialisation of $V \times W$?

Comment: Do you mean $\Bbb V \otimes \Bbb W$?

Comment: Anyway, a vector bundle is *not* "just some manifold with a projection map". In short it is a bundle whose fibers are each copies of some vector space $\Bbb V$ (which are glued together in a suitable way; see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorBundle.html).

Comment: For a bundle $\pi: E \to M$, a local trivialization is a vector bundle isomorphism $\Phi: \pi^{-1}(U) \to U \times \Bbb V$, so giving local coordinates on the latter determines adapted local coordinates on the former.

Comment: Ok great, I see. I'm now wondering how do we construct a local trivialisation for $V \otimes W$ (yes I did mean $\otimes$ in my comment, oops). As I've written it as a set in my question, I guess the projection map would be $\pi: (x,a) \to x$ but how can we use the trivlisations $\Phi_V$ and $\Phi_W$ for $V$ and $W$ to construct a trivialisation for $V \otimes W$ with respect to that projection?

Comment: Sure: Just define $\Phi_{V \otimes W}(x, v \otimes w) := \Phi_V(x, v) \otimes \Phi_W(x, w) \in V_x \otimes W_x \cong (V \otimes W)_x$. Then, extend this definition by linearity to all elements $(x, a) \in V \otimes W$; since every $(x, a)$ can be written as $\sum (x, v_i \otimes w_i)$, this defines $\Phi_{V \otimes W}$ on all of the common domain of $\Phi_V$ and $\Phi_W$.

Comment: I may be being a bit pedantic but I'd like to work this out in all detail when I'm first learning it! I'm a bit confused because as you've written it $\Phi_V$ acts on elements $(x,v)$, but surely it just acts on abstract elements of $\pi_V ^{-1}(U)$?

Comment: Here I *am* using $(x, v)$ to denote an abstract element of $\pi_V^{-1}(U)$, corresponding to the base point $x$ and the vector $v \in V_x$.

Comment: (In fact, this is the notation you used above in writing $\pi : (x, a) \to x$, is it not?)

Comment: Anyway, if you'd like to continue this, go ahead and move this discussion into chat, and I'll reply when I can.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'll see if I can digest this and fill in any details I'm missing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40464/discussion-between-wooster-and-travis).

Comment: There are still some aspects of this that are not clear to me - the local trivialisation of $V$ acts on $\pi_V^{-1}(U)$ but elements in there are not necessarily of the form $(x,v_x)$ (unless you use the local trivialisation!). I've defined $V \otimes W$ to be elements of the form $(x,u_x)$ (with $u_x \in V \otimes W$) so I can define a projection $\pi$ as I did. How can you make the local trivialisations of $V$ and $W$ act on that set?

Comment: Again, I'm using $(x, v_x)$ to denote an element of $V$ (here, $v_x$ is an element of the abstract vector space $V_x$, i.e., the fiber over $x$). This notation is standard, but it's perhaps confusing, because looks like the notation $(a, b)$ for an element of a Cartesian product, and like you say, we can only think of a vector bundle as a Cartesian product locally, and even then we require a trivialization.

Comment: Okay yes, I think I finally understand! Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Great, I'm glad you found it helpful. And you're welcome.